# Windows 10 Edition world importing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been working on a map on the java version of Minecraft for about 6 months now, and now that the Windows 10 edition of Minecraft is getting more and more features, I'd like to be able to export my world from the java version, to the Windows 10 edition.

My map is built in 1.10, and blocks like Purpur are used a lot. (blocks that aren't available on the Windows 10 edition)

In a nutshell: How do I export my minecraft worlds on the Java version to the Windows 10 edition? Do I have to wait until all blocks, features, and commands from the Java version are available on the Windows 10 edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MCEdit Unified](http://www.mcedit-unified.net/) is a third party tool which allows opening both MCPE/Win10 worlds and normal Java worlds.

You should select the area  in your Java world that you want, and export it to a .schematic file:

[image: Exporting to a schematic]

Then, open up a MCPE/Win10 world (as far as I'm aware MCEdit cannot create new MCPE/Win10 worlds, so you'll need to create one in Minecraft then load it), and use MCEdit's import tool to place the schematic you just saved into the MCPE/Win10 world:

[image: Importing a schematic]

---

Keep in mind that:

1. The current version of MCEdit unified seems very temperamental about whether or not it'll load an MCPE/Win10 world.
2. The Java version has many blocks not available in MCPE/Win10, which won't be transferred over.
3. Exporting/importing an entire world may take a long time.

It is also worth noting that you have to run MCEdit from source in order to access more modern MCPE/Win10 worlds. The instructions on how to do so are here:
https://github.com/Khroki/MCEdit-Unified

Bear in mind that the version numbers listed in the guide are not accurate, so refer to requirements.txt for the correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the Windows 10 edition doesn't support worlds created in the Java edition, and vice-versa. They used to use the the same format, but since the infinite worlds update it started to use a different, more efficient format.

Comment: That is sad. I really wanted to create some content for my kid but was surprised that world painter does not work with the new format. I tried MCEdit unified but was it was very confusing and felt a bit glitchy. Thanks Jan.