# (Minecraft) I’d like to continue playing my map which is playing in my pc version

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play one map in pc version(not java version).
Due to business trip reason, I want to export this map from pc, and then play in iPad.
After coming back, I want to play it in pc. It means, I want to export from iPad and import to pc.
Can I do it? How to do it?
Please teach my how to do this, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Edition world importing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272112/windows-10-edition-world-importing)

Comment: VTLO, this question explicitly mentions that their PC version is _not_ the Java version.

Answer (score 0):

First, go on your pc and go to the path `C:\Users\(your pc username)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\`.

Then, select your target worlds folder and [zip it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14200/windows-compress-uncompress-zip-files).  Next, change the zipped folders file extension from .zip to .mcworld. After that you send the mcworld file to your ipad. This can be done in many ways, including mail and cloud. Finally, import it to minecraft and you're done! [image: importing mcworld]